# Setting Docker for laravel app I got errors in "compose/cli/main.py

Tags: docker, laravel-5

In my Kubuntu 18.04 I try to run docker for my Laravel application

```
$ docker --version 
Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6
```

I have 3 files:

**.env:**

```
# PATHS
DB_PATH_HOST=./databases
APP_PATH_HOST=./votes
APP_PTH_CONTAINER=/var/www/html/
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: ./web/Dockerfile.yml
        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}

    db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql

    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080

    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install
```

**/web/Dockerfile.yml:**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    && a2enmod \
    rewrite
```

When I try to use `docker-compose up --build`, I get the following:

```
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ docker-compose up --build
Building web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1052, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1048, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 466, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 329, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1047, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 142, in build
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
[6769] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I know that `*.py` that is python language files, but I do not use python language or work with it, I work with PHP.

Why is an error and how to fix it?

**MODIFIED:**

```
$ docker-compose up --build
Building webapp
Step 1/2 : FROM php:7.2-apache
 ---> a7d68dad7584
Step 2/2 : RUN docker-php-ext-install     pdo_mysql     && a2enmod     rewrite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 519d1b33af81
Successfully built 519d1b33af81
Successfully tagged votes_docker_webapp:latest
Starting votes_docker_adminer_1 ... 
Starting votes_docker_composer_1 ... 
Starting votes_docker_adminer_1  ... error
votes_docker_db_1 is up-to-date

ERROR: for votes_docker_adminer_1  Cannot start service adminer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint votes_docker_adminer_1 (6e94693ab8b1a990aaa83164df0952e8665f351618a72aStarting votes_docker_composer_1 ... done

ERROR: for adminer  Cannot start service adminer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint votes_docker_adminer_1 (6e94693ab8b1a990aaa83164df0952e8665f351618a72a5531f9c3ccc18a2e3d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I tried to check related ports and got:

```
# sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 8080:8080
# sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 0.0.0.0:8080
# sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      7361/docker-proxy
```

**MODIFIED #2:**

```
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ docker-compose up --build
Creating network "votes_docker_default" with the default driver
Building webapp
Step 1/2 : FROM php:7.2-apache
 ---> a7d68dad7584
Step 2/2 : RUN docker-php-ext-install     pdo_mysql     && a2enmod     rewrite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 519d1b33af81
Successfully built 519d1b33af81
Successfully tagged votes_docker_webapp:latest
Creating votes_docker_adminer_1  ... done
Creating votes_docker_composer_1 ... done
Creating votes_docker_webapp_1   ... done
Creating votes_docker_db_1       ... done
Attaching to votes_docker_adminer_1, votes_docker_composer_1, votes_docker_webapp_1, votes_docker_db_1
adminer_1   | PHP 7.2.10 Development Server started at Mon Oct 15 10:14:02 2018
composer_1  | Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
composer_1  | To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
votes_docker_composer_1 exited with code 1
webapp_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
webapp_1    | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
webapp_1    | [Mon Oct 15 10:14:05.281793 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.2.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
webapp_1    | [Mon Oct 15 10:14:05.281843 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:06.541323Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:06.541484Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 1
db_1        | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1        | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1        | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1        | mbind: Operation not permitted
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.062202Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011071] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.062581Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.063146Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 0cd8212e-d063-11e8-8e69-0242ac140005.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.079020Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.091951Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.103829Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.103896Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.103925Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.103947Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.104006Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.104034Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.104070Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.112700Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.112738Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1        | 2018-10-15T10:14:07.117764Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.11'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

1. Is it mysql misconfigure?
2. I run it not as root.
3. Also as I use LAMP do I need to stop `apache` and `mysql` before running `docker-compose` command?

**MODIFIED #3:**

After some searching I added mysql version in my config file and added command option:

```
image: mysql:5.7.23
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password  --disable-partition-engine-check
```

and the above error was fixed.
So:

**1.** In other console under `root`  I run commands (but I'm still not sure if I need it?)

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service  mysql stop
```

**2.** Under nonroot console I run with key to run in background:

```
docker-compose up -d 
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ docker-compose down 
Stopping votes_docker_db_1      ... done
Stopping votes_docker_webapp_1  ... done
Stopping votes_docker_adminer_1 ... done
Removing votes_docker_db_1       ... done
Removing votes_docker_webapp_1   ... done
Removing votes_docker_composer_1 ... done
Removing votes_docker_adminer_1  ... done
Removing network votes_docker_default

docker-compose up -d 
Creating network "votes_docker_default" with the default driver
Creating votes_docker_webapp_1   ... done
Creating votes_docker_adminer_1  ... done
Creating votes_docker_db_1       ... done
Creating votes_docker_composer_1 ... done
```

I have no errors in output, but I expected as a result to have vendor directory in my project, as I have in `web/Dockerfile.yml`:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    && a2enmod \
    rewrite
```

But I do not see this directory...
Was the installation successful or not?

I'm not sure where to move next?

```
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ docker info
Containers: 33
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 31
Images: 19
Server Version: 17.12.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55
runc version: 9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e
init version: v0.13.0 (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-36-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.711GiB
Name: serge
ID: BDNU:HFWX:N6YV:IWYW:HJSU:SZ23:URPB:3FR2:7I3E:IFGK:AOLH:YRE5
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:                                                                                                                                                                                            
Experimental: false                                                                                                                                                                                
Insecure Registries:                                                                                                                                                                               
 127.0.0.0/8                                                                                                                                                                                       
Live Restore Enabled: false                                                                                                                                                                        

WARNING: No swap limit support

serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
votes_docker_webapp   latest              519d1b33af81        27 hours ago        378MB
adminer               latest              0038b45402de        4 weeks ago         81.7MB
composer              1.6                 e28b5b53ab28        4 weeks ago         154MB
php                   7.2-apache          a7d68dad7584        4 weeks ago         378MB
mysql                 5.7.23              563a026a1511        5 weeks ago         372MB
mysql                 5.7.22              6bb891430fb6        2 months ago        372MB
test2_php             latest              05534d47f926        3 months ago        84.7MB
test1_php             latest              05534d47f926        3 months ago        84.7MB
<none>                <none>              6060fcf4d103        3 months ago        81MB
php                   fpm-alpine          601d5b3a95d4        3 months ago        80.6MB
php                   apache              d9faf33e6e40        3 months ago        377MB
mysql                 latest              8d99edb9fd40        3 months ago        445MB
php                   7-fpm               854ffd8dc9d8        3 months ago        367MB
php                   7.2                 e86d9bb526ef        3 months ago        367MB
ukfx/php              apache-stretch      5958cb7c2316        4 months ago        648MB
nginx                 alpine              bc7fdec94612        4 months ago        18MB
hello-world           latest              e38bc07ac18e        6 months ago        1.85kB
composer/composer     latest              5afb0951f2a4        2 years ago         636MB
serge@serge:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
f8beea5dceca        mysql:5.7.23          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Restarting (2) 6 seconds ago                            votes_docker_db_1
8309b5456dcf        adminer               "entrypoint.sh docke…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                   0.0.0.0:8081->8080/tcp   votes_docker_adminer_1
cc644206931b        votes_docker_webapp   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp     votes_docker_webapp_1
```

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) documentation, `build` can be specified as a string containing a path to the build context if you have `Dockerfile` inside it.

You are using `Dockerfile.yml` file, which is not a default one (`Dockerfile`), so in this case `context` and `dockerfile` should be specified as well:

```
web:
    build:
        context: ./web
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml
```

The final `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml
        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}

    db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql

    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:8080

    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install
```

**Addition to MODIFIED part:**

Both `web` and `adminer` are configured to be allocated on port `8080` on a host system. That's why you have a conflict here. To resolve above issue you need to bind `adminer` to another port `8081` for example.

The final `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml
        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}

    db:
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql

    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8080

    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install
```

**Addition to MODIFIED3 part:**

I see the following error with your `composer` docker container:

```
composer_1  | Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
composer_1  | To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Is it because you accidentally put `${DB_PATH_HOST}` instead of `${APP_PATH_HOST}` in the `composer` config?

```
composer:
    image: composer:1.6
    volumes:
        - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install
```

Comment: Thank you!
I fixed error syntax, but I tried again and got error. Please look at MODIFIED block:

Comment: @mstdmstd added an answer to your second issue

Comment: Thank you!
I fixed port error and got next errors. Please look at MODIFIED # 2 block:

Comment: I fixed the error but have next question: Please, look at MODIFIED # 3 block.

Comment: @mstdmstd added an answer to your third issue